# Problem "WebGL is not supported by your browser" in Rmarkdown

Tags: plotly, rstudio, gpu, webgl, webgl2

I'm using `Knit to PDF` in Rstudio for a Rnotebook containing 3D graph generated by `plotly`. Then in the PDF,

[image]

When I click on the link, I have

[image]

I'm using `Rstudio 1.3.1093.0` on `Windows NT 10.0.19042`. In my GPU Diagnostics report, I have

```
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
```

My configuration is

[image]

Could you please elaborate on this problem and how to solve it? Here is the full report:

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Skia Deferred Display List: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Disabled
Surface Synchronization: Disabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Viz Service Display Compositor: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated

Problems Detected
Native GpuMemoryBuffers have been disabled, either via about:flags or command line.
Disabled Features: native_gpu_memory_buffers
Surface synchronization has been disabled by Finch trial or command line.
Disabled Features: surface_synchronization
Viz service display compositor is not enabled by default.
Disabled Features: viz_display_compositor
Skia renderer is not used by default.
Disabled Features: skia_renderer
Skia deferred display list is not used by default.
Disabled Features: skia_deferred_display_list

Version Information
Data exported   2020-12-31T09:56:49.979Z
Chrome version  rstudio/1.3.1093.0
Operating system    Windows NT 10.0.19042
Software rendering list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/cdec0adf58c577876de3d8f073dce520f0829431/gpu/config/software_rendering_list.json
Driver bug list URL https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/cdec0adf58c577876de3d8f073dce520f0829431/gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_list.json
ANGLE commit id unknown hash
2D graphics backend Skia/69 e110fd1ebd2d559838c49a8821ebf18986bd6ec2-
Command Line    "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/rstudio.exe" --ignore-gpu-blacklist --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-viewport --disable-renderer-accessibility --browser-subprocess-path="C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\QtWebEngineProcess.exe" --no-sandbox --enable-threaded-compositing --disable-zero-copy --disable-gpu-memory-buffer-compositor-resources --disable-gpu-memory-buffer-video-frames --disable-es3-gl-context --enable-features=AllowContentInitiatedDataUrlNavigations --disable-features=SurfaceSynchronization --disable-features=SurfaceSynchronization,MojoVideoCapture --disable-features=SurfaceSynchronization,MojoVideoCapture,UseVideoCaptureApiForDevToolsSnapshots --disable-features=SurfaceSynchronization,MojoVideoCapture,UseVideoCaptureApiForDevToolsSnapshots,UseModernMediaControls --create-default-gl-context --use-gl=desktop --in-process-gpu --gpu-preferences=KAAAAAAAAACiAwCAAQAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAAAEAAAAIAAAAAAAAACgAAAAEAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAoAAAAAAAAADAAAAAAAAAAOAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAABAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAoAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAEAAAALAAAA --use-gl=desktop "C:/Program Files/RStudio/none"
Driver Information
Initialization time 9
In-process GPU  true
Passthrough Command Decoder false
Sandboxed   false
GPU0    VENDOR = 0x8086, DEVICE= 0x3e9b *ACTIVE*
GPU1    VENDOR = 0x10de, DEVICE= 0x1c20
Optimus false
AMD switchable  false
Desktop compositing Aero Glass
Direct Composition  false
Supports overlays   false
Overlay capabilities
Diagonal Monitor Size of \\.\DISPLAY1   15.5"
Driver D3D12 feature level  Not supported
Driver Vulkan API version   Not supported
Driver vendor   Intel Corporation
Driver version  25.20.100.6577
Driver date 2-7-2019
Pixel shader version    4.50
Vertex shader version   4.50
Max. MSAA samples   16
Machine model name  
Machine model version   
GL_VENDOR   Intel
GL_RENDERER Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
GL_VERSION  4.5.0 - Build 25.20.100.6577
GL_EXTENSIONS   GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_bindless_texture GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_cl_event GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_compatibility GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_cull_distance GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_direct_state_access GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_draw_indirect GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_fragment_shader_interlock GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_geometry_shader4 GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_gl_spirv GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_indirect_parameters GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect GL_ARB_multisample GL_ARB_multitexture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp GL_ARB_post_depth_coverage GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_robustness_isolation GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_shader_group_vote GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_shader_subroutine GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_spirv_extensions GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_tessellation_shader GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32 GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_direct_state_access GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_EXT_texture3D GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_INTEL_conservative_rasterization GL_INTEL_fragment_shader_ordering GL_INTEL_framebuffer_CMAA GL_INTEL_map_texture GL_INTEL_multi_rate_fragment_shader GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_WIN_swap_hint WGL_EXT_swap_control
Disabled Extensions 
Disabled WebGL Extensions   
Window system binding vendor    
Window system binding version   
Window system binding extensions    WGL_EXT_depth_float WGL_ARB_buffer_region WGL_ARB_extensions_string WGL_ARB_make_current_read WGL_ARB_pixel_format WGL_ARB_pbuffer WGL_EXT_extensions_string WGL_EXT_swap_control WGL_ARB_multisample WGL_ARB_pixel_format_float WGL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB WGL_ARB_create_context WGL_ARB_create_context_profile WGL_EXT_pixel_format_packed_float WGL_EXT_create_context_es_profile WGL_EXT_create_context_es2_profile WGL_NV_DX_interop WGL_INTEL_cl_sharing WGL_NV_DX_interop2 WGL_ARB_create_context_robustness WGL_ARB_context_flush_control
Direct rendering    Yes
Reset notification strategy 0x8261
GPU process crash count 0
Compositor Information
Tile Update Mode    One-copy
Partial Raster  Enabled
GpuMemoryBuffers Status
ATC Software only
ATCIA   Software only
DXT1    Software only
DXT5    Software only
ETC1    Software only
R_8 Software only
R_16    Software only
RG_88   Software only
BGR_565 Software only
RGBA_4444   Software only
RGBX_8888   GPU_READ, SCANOUT
RGBA_8888   GPU_READ, SCANOUT
BGRX_8888   Software only
BGRX_1010102    Software only
RGBX_1010102    Software only
BGRA_8888   Software only
RGBA_F16    Software only
YVU_420 Software only
YUV_420_BIPLANAR    Software only
UYVY_422    Software only
Display(s) Information
Info    Display[2528732444] bounds=[0,0 1536x864], workarea=[0,0 1536x824], scale=1.25, external.
Color space information {primaries:BT709, transfer:IEC61966_2_1, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}
Bits per color component    8
Bits per pixel  24
Video Acceleration Information
Encode h264 baseline    up to 3840x2176 pixels and/or 30.000 fps
Encode h264 main    up to 3840x2176 pixels and/or 30.000 fps
Encode h264 high    up to 3840x2176 pixels and/or 30.000 fps
Diagnostics
... loading ...
```

Comment: @Andrea Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood in my previous comments, I have deleted them and posted an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can embed WebGL HTML5 content into a PDF.

Comment: Actually, I follow the instruction from https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html.

Comment: The page you links to says “They were originally designed for HTML output only, and they require the availability of JavaScript, so they will not work in non-HTML output formats, such as LaTeX/PDF.”

Comment: The fact some HTML works doesn't mean all will.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaboration. Hope the feature "Knit to PDF" will solve this bug soon.